# Is it possible to append layers to a KML file in R?

Tags: r, kml, sf

I'm trying to create a KML file containing two layers to display in Google Earth.

Here's a small example of what I've tried:

```
library(sf)

poly <- st_as_sf(st_as_sfc(
  "POLYGON ((-59.6354 5.0372, -59.3598 5.0372, -59.3598 5.3175, -59.6354 5.3175, -59.6354 5.0372))"
  , crs = 4326
))
pt <- st_as_sf(st_as_sfc(
  "POINT (-59.6354 5.0372)"
  , crs = 4326
))

# Using GeoPackage, it works as expected
st_write(poly, "test.gpkg", layer = "outlines")
st_write(pt, "test.gpkg", layer = "points", append = TRUE)

# Using KML produces an error
st_write(poly, "test.kml", layer = "outlines")
st_write(pt, "test.kml", layer = "points", append = TRUE)
# Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
#   Cannot append to existing dataset.
```

I still hope that it is possible to achieve a two-layer KML with R, though, since it's also possible to just piece one together using a text editor:

`desired_output.kml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Folder><name>outlines</name>
  <Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
      <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-59.6354,5.0372 -59.3598,5.0372 -59.3598,5.3175 -59.6354,5.3175 -59.6354,5.0372</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
<Folder><name>points</name>
  <Placemark>
      <Point><coordinates>-59.6354,5.0372</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

This is compatible with Google Earth and does exactly what I want. Is there any way to achieve this using R?

Comment: Note the `append` option to `st_write` controls the appending of data to existing layers, not the adding of extra layers to existing data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write one, then write the other, but make sure you specify the "LIBKML" driver (which needs compiling into your GDAL, and should be the default for kml but I need to specify it...):

```
> st_write(poly, dsn="test22.kml", driver="LIBKML", layer="poly")
Writing layer `poly' to data source `test22.kml' using driver `LIBKML'
Writing 1 features with 0 fields and geometry type Polygon.
> st_write(pt, dsn="test22.kml", driver="LIBKML", layer="pt")
Writing layer `pt' to data source `test22.kml' using driver `LIBKML'
Writing 1 features with 0 fields and geometry type Point.
```

Then the resulting KML has two layers:

```
> ogrinfo("test22.kml")
[1] "INFO: Open of `test22.kml'"             
[2] "      using driver `LIBKML' successful."
[3] "1: poly"                                
[4] "2: pt"
```

It separates the layers into two `<Document>` elements and doesn't use `<Folder>` elements like you have in your sample output, but I'm not sure if that will affect your use case adversely...

If it uses the KML driver I only get the most recent layer written:

```
> st_write(poly, dsn="testfail.kml", layer="poly")
Writing layer `poly' to data source `testfail.kml' using driver `KML'
Writing 1 features with 0 fields and geometry type Polygon.
> st_write(pt, dsn="testfail.kml", layer="pt")
Writing layer `pt' to data source `testfail.kml' using driver `KML'
Writing 1 features with 0 fields and geometry type Point.
> ogrinfo("testfail.kml")
[1] "INFO: Open of `testfail.kml'"           
[2] "      using driver `LIBKML' successful."
[3] "1: pt"                                  
>
```

So, use `driver="LIBKML"` if you can...